# How to get tags in cucumber world.object

Tags: tags, puppeteer, cucumberjs

So I have a Cucumberjs/puppeteer framework.  I was wondering if there was a way to access the passed cucumber tag (example: @smokeTest) in the world object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md, world will be accessible as 'this' in both world and hooks file.

Option 1:

As per your request, you can try in below way to fetch which tags you are executing at present:

1) Create a file called hooks
2) Add

```
Before({tags: '@tagName'}, async function() {
this['tags'] = [];
this['tags'].push('@tagName');
console.log(this);
});
```

3) In this case, when your scenario holds tag name matches with Before function tag name in hooks file, respective tag name will be added to 'this' object.

Below output will be printed in the console:

```
{
tags:[ '@tagName' ]
}
```

Here tagName is an example and this can be replaced with any of the name (As per your request it is @SmokeTest) and the output will be in this format:

```
{
    tags:[ '@SmokeTest' ]
    }
```

Option 2:
Hope you are passing tag name in your npm scripts like --tags=@tagName. 
If you console process.argv, it will print all the commands what you are passing in that npm script including '--tags=@tagName' in Array format.

Using this array, you can repeat a loop based on its length and extract tagName from the matched string like below:

```
let option: string;
    process.argv.forEach(arg => {
        if (arg.includes('tags')) {
            option = arg;
            this['tags'] = [];
            this['tags'].push(option.replace('--tags=', ''));
        }
    });
```

Now, if you console 'this', it will include a key with the name 'tags' like below:

```
{
    tags:[ '@tagName' ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access a list of all tags, as well as other information about the scenario in the `Before` hook using the [pickle object from Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/gherkin#pickles):

```js
Before(function ({ pickle }) {
    this.tags = pickle.tags.map(i => i.name);
});
```

Once the `tags` array is added to the world object, you can access it from any step definition in your scenario.

Live Demonstration: https://testjam.io/?p=od8QsClhFjmZB6zOsEyI

Comment: Thanks - I found the pickle object on some post somewhere.  :)